# Azure WIndows B1S instance-Internet

Tags: azure

Hello I am going to use Azure Windows B1S instance. I have excel with macro which gets live values from web. Once I connected vm through Remote Desktop, and start excel and close. will excel run through without problem if I am closing Remote Desktop? and also will my excel connected to internet to get live values if I disconnected VM from my local pc?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your application is a process, yes. After the window is closed, it will be continued and where it is connected when maintaining the previous state of the vm. Activate a pop-up that appears before closing that asks if you just want to close a window or suspend a vm. Select only to close.

Comment: thank u ...but what about internet connection sir? if application is running after my local pc closed, still my application has accessing internet ?